# Creating LINESTRING from two POINT(s) and finding mid-POINT

Tags: geopandas, linestring, points-to-line, geodataframe

I would like to create a `LINESTRING` from two `POINT` geometries and then determine the mid-POINT. So, from my original Pandas' DataFrame, with `"x"` and `"y"` columns, I created the following GeoPandas' DataFrame:

```py
zone_short_edges = 
 id  vertex_id                    fr_point  \
1  A1                2  POINT (119.79008 28.35047)   
3  A1                4  POINT (122.85067 44.85106)   
5  A2                1  POINT (138.79141 26.48802)   
7  A2                3  POINT (141.73386 44.89716)   

                     to_point  seg_length  
1  POINT (122.85067 28.08433)    3.072140  
3  POINT (119.92314 44.71798)    2.930553  
5  POINT (141.92247 26.26168)    3.139230  
7  POINT (138.79141 44.89716)    2.942450
```

where `fr_point` and `to_point` are `dtype = geometry`.

Now, I am facing two choices:

1. Create a `LINESTRING` for each pair and then finding that linestrings midpoint.
2. Finding the midpoint (what I actually want to the possibility to find all the `POINT(s)` that divide the segment into `N` segments of equal length).

I tried doing this:

```py
geometry = [xy for xy in zip(zone_short_edges.fr_point, zone_short_edges.to_point)]
LineString([geometry]).wkt
```

but that was a clear failure.

Any ideas that might put me in the right direction or do I really need to go to my original DataFrame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df['line'] = df.apply(lambda row: LineString([row['fr_point'], row['to_point']]), axis=1) #Create a linestring column
df['midpoint'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['line'].centroid, axis=1) #Find centroid

df.head().to_clipboard()
```

[image]